# Q:UITableView scrollview delegate method did not pass the special code

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

In the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method, did not pass the special code:
I want to fade show my custom `navigationbar`, which is by `alpha`, the `uiview animation` and directly set `alpha = 1` did not work.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == _tableview){

        currentContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        // 0 ~ 358  -20 ~ 338
        /*float alpha_of_scroll = (currentOffsetY + 20) / 358.0;

        [self setNavAlpha:alpha_of_scroll];

        _narBarView.alpha = 1 - alpha_of_scroll;*/

        NSLog(@"%f", currentContentOffset);

        // up scroll
        if (lastContentOffset > currentContentOffset) {

            if (currentContentOffset == 250) {

                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

                    _lml_cal_view.alpha = 0.0;  // this code did not pass
                    _narBarView.alpha = 1.0;  // this code did not pass.
                }];
            }
        }
        // down scroll
        else {

            if (currentContentOffset == 250 ) {


                _lml_cal_view.alpha = 1.0;  // this code did not pass.
                _narBarView.alpha = 0.0;  // this code did not pass 
                /*[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{


                }];*/
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The scrollView delegate's method `scrollViewDiDScroll:` callback is discontinuous.    
So the code below is not suitable, If you're lucky enough, the code will pass inside your condition.

Comment: @zylenv I have take breakpoint on the line:`if (currentContentOffset == 250 ) {`, I make sure it break in the line.

Comment: Yeah, you did pass the line, but the currentContentOffset is discontinuous. So the condition can not be establishment.